# Accessing AEM Dialog Field Options From Template Dialog

Tags: java, aem, sling

I'm interested in getting the available options for a given template component. **I'm not interested in the values in the dialog**, but all of the possible fields specified in the dialog (both inherited and component specific) (whether they currently have values or not). How can I do this?

I am able to access the `dialog` node for a component and manually iterate and filter down (looking for nodes with `name` and `fieldLabel`).

But I am stuck on getting inherited dialog properties from the classic UI dialog options for the base page component (`/libs/wcm/foundation/components/page`) component, because the dialog options live in files such as: `/libs/wcm/foundation/components/page/v1/page/tab_basic.infinity.json`. These files don't seem to live in AEM at that location, so where are they really located?

In the end, I want to specify a template component, and return back all of the possible dialog fields in a List or Hash.

Answer (score 0):

You could AEM let you handle the dirty work, by addressing your dialog with `.overlay.infinity.json` via HTTP request, parse the JSON with the native Sling JSON api and iterate over the resulting `JSONObject` tree.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want, but it does not recursively include the `cqinclude` options ([see here for the foundation base page](http://localhost:4502/libs/foundation/components/page/dialog.overlay.infinity.json). This has led me down a good rabbit hole however, so thank you

Comment: I was hoping for a magic selector to recursively include all, but it seems like multiple calls are needed in order to get the `cqinclude` dialog data. Even when you open the OOTB page properties there are multiple calls if you watch your browser network tab

Comment: This is just a suggestion ... but did you checkout the Resource Merger API?